# Moving a DOM element in Jquery with YUI event listeners?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, yui

I have a DOM element that has YUI event listeners on elements inside of it. I'm trying to get the DOM element to go on a different part of the page, but once I do that, I seem to lose the events that were set in YUI. Does anyone know of a way around this?

Comment: YUI and jQuery together? Why?

Comment: Please don't use 2 libraries. Use one. Preferably jQuery.

Comment: Without seeing the code, it's hard to tell.  Just moving an element to a different location should not detach the event handlers.

Comment: Guess; the div's event handing is delegated to an ancestor element? If so, then by moving the div to somewhere else in the DOM, that delegation will be lost.

Comment: Could you define how you are moving this element? Some show of code would help.

Comment: For people wondering why I was using two libraries. I am working on a very large codebase where part of the code is in jQuery and part of it in YUI. If it was a fresh product, I would stick to one language, but sometimes you get stuck between a rock and a hard place. It was not by choice.

Comment: @Geuis using 2 libraries ok IMO.  AngularJS, for example, depends on jQuery (really jquery lite or jquery).  So everyone using AngularJS has at minimum two libraries.  It really depends on your needs :)

Answer (score -1):

I'm facing exactly the same issue. I have both YUI and jQuery in the same app because it is a previously existing app originally built with YUI and I'm trying to use jQuery for implementing a functionality which is easier to achieve with jQuery.

As I have experienced, you shouldn't lose YUI events just by moving the element:

```
jQuery("#element1").before(jQuery("#element2"));
```

On the other hand, it will be a problem if you try to clone and swap elements, [even using the clone function with arguments for cloning events as well](http://api.jquery.com/clone/):

```
var copy_to = $(to).clone(true);
var copy_from = $(this).clone(true);
$(to).replaceWith(copy_from);
$(this).replaceWith(copy_to);
```

According to that, I would say it is not possible to CLONE elements preserving events bound using YUI, but it is possible to MOVE them.

**EDIT:**
This is how I'm moving and swapping two DOM elements which have YUI events bound:

```
  function makeElementAsDragAndDrop(elem) {
     $(elem).draggable({
         //snap : '#droppable',
         snapMode : 'outer',
         revert : "invalid",
         helper: function(event) { // This is a fix as helper: "original" doesn't work well
            return $(this).clone().width($(this).width());
          },
         zIndex : 100,
         handle: ".title"
     });
     $(elem).droppable({
         //activeClass : "ui-state-hover",
         //hoverClass : "ui-state-active",
         drop : function(event, ui) {
            var sourcePlaceholder = $( "<div/>", 
               {
                  id: "sourcePlaceholder"
               }).insertBefore(ui.draggable);

            var targetPlaceholder = $( "<div/>", 
               {
                  id: "targetPlaceholder"
               }).insertBefore(this);

            $(ui.draggable).insertBefore(targetPlaceholder);
            $(this).insertBefore(sourcePlaceholder);

            sourcePlaceholder.remove();
            targetPlaceholder.remove();
         },
         tolerance : "pointer"
     });
  }
```

As you can see, the code above is part of the DIVs drag&drop implementation I'm writing using jQuery.

Hope it helps.

PS: If somebody knows how to clone elements preserving events bound using YUI, please let us know!

Comment: You're doing it wrong. Not your code, which honestly I just didn't read. There is *no* circumstance, and I literally mean none, in which you should be using more than 1 library in the same page. That answer was true in January, and its still true now.

Comment: @Geuis I'm sorry but I just cannot accept your comment as it is (and your vote down either by the way) unless you provide either a reasoned explanation or any link, resource, etc. If you are right, I humbly think the best way of collaborating and contributing to the community is by providing a "formal" answer to the question raised by Pragun Vhora. I still have reasons for thinking it is not wrong at all to use both libraries, so I'm looking forward to read and understand the mentioned explanation.

Comment: You definitely have the right to disagree. That's why I responded in a comment and not as an answer. That wouldn't have been constructive. When I said, "You're doing it wrong", I didn't say that because I'm being a troll. I say it from *experience*. I used to have to maintain a project that was written with YUI 2.4.x. A previous developer had imported jQuery to do mixed functionality. It was a nightmare. I didn't mind at first, as the jQuery code was easier to maintain and write. But in many cases, I ran into exactly the issues you and Pragun are.

Comment: Both libs handle event binding very deeply and differently. Mixing and matching them is just not a good idea. Its brittle and hard to maintain. Things get lost. Largely, I or others could help both of you solve your specific problem. But that isn't going to help you in the long run. Providing you a bandaid just delays the decision you and your team(s) need to make to either stick with YUI or switch over to jQuery. That's just the bottom line. Good luck.

Comment: What you say sounds now reasonable. On the other hand, I think every scenario is different and I think sometimes there are exceptions. As I said before, I'm creating extensions for Alfresco Share which are developed and deployed independently to the webapp hence I cannot change the out-of-the-box source code, just compliment what already exists. Alfresco Share has been developed mainly using YUI2 for doing client-side stuff, but it's funny it also comes with jQuery what means you can just use it without adding it as part of your extension source code.

Comment: Furthermore, there are some popular extensions (like this https://code.google.com/p/fme-alfresco-extensions/wiki/GalleryPlusDashlet) which has been developed using jQuery, Mootools or whatever mixing libraries as a consequence. My conclusion: what you state makes very sense and has to be strongly considered but I understand there could be exceptions as I mentioned, always previously evaluating and taking into account potential conflicts and risks.

Comment: Please, don't take this the wrong way. But when you mention Alfresco Share and that it has mixed libraries, this really is the epitome of bad enterprise-ish software. If I was a customer evaluating products to use, simply spending the 5 minutes reading this thread and the documentation overviews of Alfresco Share should scare me away to use something else. I guess deep down, I'm trying to present a world-view that this entire class of software is a money and soul sucking misadventure in mismanagement, upset developers, and poor final products. Typically business managers buy this, not devs.